# Excel Add-in Only saves once then generates another excel and crashes

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, excel-addins

So im working now with excel add-in and i have a function to force-save the document and upload it to a storage. It works when you press-it the first time, but then it opens a new excel-window with a random number for example "F7E57000" and instead of force-saving it prompts to save to somewhere in the disk. If i press save then the original window with the opened add-in dissapears, and if i press cancel then excel crashes.

this is the code from the add-in function

```
$(".uploadBack").click(function (e) {
            Excel.run(function (context) {
                context.workbook.save(Excel.SaveBehavior.save);
                return context.sync().then(() => {
                    return Office.context.document.getFilePropertiesAsync(function (asyncResult) {
                        return new OfficeExtension.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                            var fileUrl = asyncResult.value.url;
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "/uploadPlantaBack",
                                data: {
                                    filePath: fileUrl,
                                    id: e.currentTarget.dataset.escenarioid,
                                    descripcion: $("#Descripcion").val(),
                                    comentario: $("#Comentario").val()
                                },
                                type: "POST",
                                success: function (response) {
                                    Swal.fire({
                                        position: 'center',
                                        type: 'success',
                                        title: 'La configuracion se subio con exito',
                                        showConfirmButton: false,
                                        timer: 1500
                                    })
                                    resolve();
                                },
                                error: function (error) {
                                    Swal.fire({
                                        position: 'center',
                                        type: 'error',
                                        title: error,
                                        showConfirmButton: true
                                        
                                    })
                                    reject();
                                }
                            });
                        })
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

Update: Before this problem happens, i load a document in the function with the addfrombase64 function,  which is in beta office.js. Here is the code where it receives an url with the excel file in a storage and then it parses the entire file to base 64

```
$(".excelReplica").click(function (e) {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: '/toBase64',
                                data: { url: e.currentTarget.dataset.url },
                                success: function (base64String) {
                                    Excel.run(function (context) {
                                        return new OfficeExtension.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                                            var sheets = context.workbook.worksheets;
                                            sheets.load("items/name");
                                            context.sync().then(() => {
                                                var countSheets = sheets.items.length;
                                                sheets.addFromBase64(
                                                    base64String,
                                                    null, // get all the worksheets
                                                    Excel.WorksheetPositionType.after, // insert them after the worksheet specified by the next parameter
                                                    sheets.getActiveWorksheet() // insert them after the active worksheet
                                                );
                                                sheets.load("items/name");
                                                context.sync().then(() => {

                                                    var firstSheet = sheets.items[countSheets];
                                                    firstSheet.activate();
                                                    firstSheet.load(firstSheet.name);

                                                    for (var i = countSheets - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                                                        sheets.items[i].delete();
                                                    }
                                                    context.sync().then(() => {
                                                        window.location = '/Escenarios/Details/' + e.currentTarget.dataset.id;
                                                    });
                                                });

                                            });
                                            resolve();
                                        });

                                    });
                                },
                                error: function (a) {

                                }
                            });
                        });
```

Comment: it looks to me like a bug, it should not crash the Excel at any time, but it seems your sample code cannot be run as expected in my side. in order to help us to repro and locate the issue, would you please help us by exporting a script lab gist? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/explore-with-script-lab#save-and-share-snippets

Comment: So i made the gist it is right here https://gist.github.com/UnForastero/9c3f78d9f02ad22f42f47316f0314bd4 and the thing is that it works fine when creating a new document.

Maybe it doesnt work because the excel in first place is in read-only mode when debugging in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks @Nino, I just had a try on your gist, it works fine here. based on your comments above, does it mean that you find the root cause of this issue?

Comment: Sadly no. I have tried in a non read-only excel file and still have document with the number for example 0BF90300. Like i said it works once and then it crashes, i have to open de excel file again to save. I think its something like a overflow of memory. Dont know if there is something to flush it if what im saying is true.

Comment: I updated the question where i use a function from the beta version from office.js maybe the problem is there.